# set command key in Mac OS virtual machine with pc host

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and virtualising Mac OS Sierra in Virtualbox. How can I set up the Apple command key with my keyboard in the virtual machine ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: Close voters: This is on-topic. It's not confirmed that OP has non-Apple hardware; this question would be the same if Ubuntu was installed on any kind of Mac and used with an external keyboard as non-Apple hardware. As such, this question is answerable [per Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/a/12052).

Comment: I'm running an OSX virtualbox on a MacBook Pro... I'll go for this question!